# NSmutableArray with dictionnarie value how to count specif value?

Tags: xcode, dictionary, nsmutablearray, tableview

I have a mutablearray with dictionnairies. i would like to count how many dictionnary have a specific value ?

NSDictionary    *question = [self.tabQuestionnaire objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[question objectForKey:@"theme"]

Answer (score 1):

-(NSInteger)countValue:( NSString * )value forKey: ( NSString * )key{

NSInteger result=0;

```
 for (NSDictionary *question in self.tabQuestionnaire){
    if ([value isEqualToString: [question objectForKey:key]]){
       result++;
 }

return result;
```

}

Comment: thanks. Know i find the number of object for section, how can i populater correctly my array in it ?

Comment: what do you mean ? what array to populate ? Do you want save for later the counting result of each key ?

Comment: i find the solution, i generate a nsmutabledictionnary and add objets sort in the right order.